# How to set array starting and end indices in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-playground

I tried to create an array from 1-100 elements create in playground, but while i'm trying to print it doesn't print the values in the array.

code:

```
var ab:Array = [1...100]

for i in ab {
    print(i)
}
```

output: 
[image]

But in the playground it didn't shown any error.
Did i do anything wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Option-click on `ab` to see what kind of value you created ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You create an array of `Range<Int>` elements (a single one, `1..<101`)

```
var ab: Array = [1...100] // element TYPE inferred from 1...100
                          // to be Range<Int>
print(ab.dynamicType)
   // Array<Range<Int>>
```

But I assume you're attempting to create an array of 100 `Int` elements.

```
var ab = Array(1...100) // Array with elements intialized to Int,
                        // using Range<Int> to intialize

for i in ab {
    print(i)
} // 1 2 3 ... 100
```

If you're only looking to print the numbers in the range `1...100`, you needn't necessarily create an array if integers to do so (or an array at all). Instead, you could use a single `Range<Int>` variable and loop over the elements contained in this range. E.g.

```
let myRange = 1...5 // inferred as type Range<Int>

for i in myRange {
    print(i) // the type of 'i' is Int, the same as in
             // the array case above.
} // 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear` and `effective` ;

```
var ab = Array(1...100)
for i in ab {
    print(i)
}
```

`Output`

> 1 2 3.... 100